# How to get html class content of external page and store it in text file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to store Alexa's country rank of specific website in a daily basis and store it in a database or text file.
I don't have and knowledge in Javascript of jQuery.

Would you please help me?

Comment: This is a task for your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out google firebase:
Specifically firebase functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
Using firebase functions you can write code that runs periodically and fetches data from the website you wanted and then stores it in google realtime database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

If you just want this data for local use you can setup a batch file using a thing called curl: https://curl.se/ to make web requests and store the result in a text file. Then use the windows task scheduler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler to make the batch file run periodically and automatically.